# Too much space-around between flex items in mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox

how to reduced the space between the flex items in mobile view? I already use gap or margin in flex items but still no luck. Here is my code for your reference. Thankyou

[image: sample view in mobile]

I am expecting to reduce the space between the app title and description and my login form for mobile view only, it works fine in desktop view. Thankyou

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #181818;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form-group {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #dadada;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"]:focus {
  border: 1px solid #0066cc;
}

button {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.btn-info {
  border: 1px solid #2157eb;
  background-color: #2157eb;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-success {
  border: 1px solid #1fa167;
  background-color: #1fa167;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #0066cc;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.index-page-flexcon1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  gap: 40px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.index-page-flexcon1 .flexbox-item-1 {
  max-width: 380px;
  text-align: center;
}

.index-page-flexcon1 .flexbox-item-1 h1 {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #3496e6 30%, #a465d9 70%);
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.index-page-flexcon1 .flexbox-item-1 p {
  color: #c4c4c4;
}

.index-page-flexcon1 .flexbox-item-2 {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  text-align: center;
}

.index-page-flexcon1 .flexbox-item-2 .btn-info {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.index-page-flexcon1 .flexbox-item-2 .btn-success {
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, interactive-widget=resizes-content">

  <link rel="preload" href="assets/css/style.css?version=<?php echo rand(0, 100); ?>" as="style" onload="this.onload=null; this.rel='stylesheet';">
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css?version=<?php echo rand(0, 100); ?>"></noscript>

  <!-- boxicons link -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <title>WeChitChat</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flexbox-container index-page-flexcon1">
    <div class="flexbox-item-1">
      <h1>WeChitChat</h1>
      <p>
        <span class="icon"><i class='bx bxs-heart'></i></span> Simple,
        <span class="icon"><i class='bx bxs-zap'></i></span> Fast and
        <span class="icon"><i class='bx bxs-check-shield'></i></span> Secured. Stay connected to your friends and family
        <span class="special-text">Anytime, Anywhere.</span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="flexbox-item-2">
      <form action="">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" name="" id="" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn-info">Log In</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <hr>
          <a href="#" class="btn-link">Forgot your password?</a><br/>
          <button type="button" class="btn-success">Register an account</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make a working snippet to debug or post the code which you have tried at least

Comment: snippet was added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding the `align-content` property (for when items wrap — which they can only do by adding `flex-wrap: wrap`):

```css
.index-page-flexcon1 {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
}
```

(Other options include `align-content: flex-start` etc.)